# Docker: Message displays only unsupported

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-machine

I am running docker on windows with linux container, and trying to push a spring boot project with docker file to heroku.

Docker file :

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} forceCI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT [“java”,”-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom”,”-jar”,”/forceCI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar”]
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.forceCI</groupId>
    <artifactId>forceCI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>forceCI</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <docker.image.prefix>forceci</docker.image.prefix>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.kohsuke/github-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kohsuke</groupId>
            <artifactId>github-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.94</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sparkjava/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ant/ant -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ant/ant-launcher -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.5</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Now from cli, i typed the following.

```
heroku login
heroku container:login
heroku create forceci
docker build -t force_ci:v1 .

C:\ForceCI\forceCI\forceCI>docker images                
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
force_ci            v1                  36256495fa8f        26 seconds ago      150MB
openjdk             8-jdk-alpine        54ae553cb104        5 weeks ago         103MB
```

Now I did `heroku container:push web --app forceci`:

```
C:\ForceCI\forceCI\forceCI>heroku container:push web --app forceci         
=== Building web (C:\ForceCI\forceCI\forceCI\Dockerfile)
Sending build context to Docker daemon  47.44MB
Step 1/5 : FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
 ---> 54ae553cb104
Step 2/5 : VOLUME /tmp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 336a1d2d2af5
Step 3/5 : ARG JAR_FILE
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1d5639ba8638
Step 4/5 : ADD ${JAR_FILE} forceCI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 02d8baa57cfd
Step 5/5 : ENTRYPOINT [“java”,”-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom”,”-jar”,”/forceCI-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar”]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 36256495fa8f
Successfully built 36256495fa8f
Successfully tagged registry.heroku.com/forceci/web:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions fo
r sensitive files and directories.
=== Pushing web (C:\ForceCI\forceCI\forceCI\Dockerfile)
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/forceci/web]
39c03b6d47b3: Pushed
f2ec1bba02a6: Layer already exists
0c3170905795: Layer already exists
df64d3292fd6: Layer already exists
unsupported
 !    Error: docker push exited with 1
```

I get error unsupported.

Now I did docker images to check what images have been build, and I got this:

```
C:\ForceCI\forceCI\forceCI>docker images                                   
REPOSITORY                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
force_ci                          v1                  36256495fa8f        6 minutes ago       150MB
registry.heroku.com/forceci/web   latest              36256495fa8f        6 minutes ago       150MB
openjdk                           8-jdk-alpine        54ae553cb104        5 weeks ago         103MB
```

Then I thought to push the already built images to heroku, but still got the unsupported message.

```
C:\ForceCI\forceCI\forceCI>docker tag force_ci:v1 registry.heroku.com/forceci/web           

C:\ForceCI\forceCI\forceCI>docker push registry.heroku.com/forceci/web         
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/forceci/web]
39c03b6d47b3: Layer already exists
f2ec1bba02a6: Layer already exists
0c3170905795: Layer already exists
df64d3292fd6: Layer already exists
unsupported
```

Can someone help here?

Log file shows:

```
[13:25:04.257][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
[13:25:04.257][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script '$(Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8).InterfaceIndex[0]'...
[13:25:06.337][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] time="2018-10-22T13:25:06+05:30" msg="proxy >> GET /_ping\n"
[13:25:06.340][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] time="2018-10-22T13:25:06+05:30" msg="proxy << GET /_ping\n"
[13:25:06.846][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] time="2018-10-22T13:25:06+05:30" msg="proxy >> POST /v1.39/images/registry.heroku.com/forceci/web/push?tag=\n"
[13:25:09.988][VpnKit         ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6

[13:25:09.988][VpnKit         ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 52.218.80.36

[13:25:10.665][VpnKit         ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:52.218.80.36:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof

[13:25:14.597][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
[13:25:14.597][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script '$(Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8).InterfaceIndex[0]'...
[13:25:14.697][VpnKit         ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6

[13:25:14.697][VpnKit         ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 52.218.104.194

[13:25:16.019][VpnKit         ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6

[13:25:16.019][VpnKit         ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 52.218.49.108

[13:25:16.989][VpnKit         ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6

[13:25:16.989][VpnKit         ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 52.218.17.20

[13:25:18.064][VpnKit         ][Error  ] vpnkit.exe: Socket.TCPv4.write tcp:52.218.17.20:443: caught Bad file descriptor returning Eof

[13:25:22.592][VpnKit         ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6

[13:25:22.592][VpnKit         ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 52.218.53.170

[13:25:24.929][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
[13:25:24.929][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script '$(Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8).InterfaceIndex[0]'...
[13:25:29.226][VpnKit         ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6

[13:25:29.226][VpnKit         ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 52.218.48.20

[13:25:31.233][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] time="2018-10-22T13:25:31+05:30" msg="proxy << POST /v1.39/images/registry.heroku.com/forceci/web/push?tag=\n"
[13:25:31.233][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] time="2018-10-22T13:25:31+05:30" msg="Cancel connection..."
[13:25:31.234][ApiProxy       ][Warning] time="2018-10-22T13:25:31+05:30" msg="ignored error: HvSocket has been closed for write"
[13:25:40.447][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
[13:25:40.447][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script '$(Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8).InterfaceIndex[0]'...
[13:25:51.873][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
[13:25:51.873][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script '$(Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8).InterfaceIndex[0]'...
[13:25:57.140][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
[13:25:57.140][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script '$(Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8).InterfaceIndex[0]'...
[13:26:02.324][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
[13:26:02.324][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script '$(Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8).InterfaceIndex[0]'...
[13:26:12.678][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
[13:26:12.678][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script '$(Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8).InterfaceIndex[0]'...
[13:26:50.195][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
[13:26:50.195][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script '$(Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8).InterfaceIndex[0]'...
[13:27:00.708][DnsUpdater     ][Info   ] Network configuration change detected
[13:27:00.708][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script '$(Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 8.8.8.8).InterfaceIndex[0]'...
```

Comment: Which version of docker are you using locally?

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU Version: 18.09.0-ce-beta1 client server both

Comment: Has anyone not yet faced this issue?

Comment: Facing a similar issue where `heroku container:push ...` results in "unsupported"

Comment: @RyanRodemoyer Just now found a build which works. Answered below.

Comment: @RyanRodemoyer  Any luck with this one?

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by changing the final line of my `Dockerfile`.

Originally, the file provided by the Visual Studio template used the following to launch the webapp within the container:

`ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "YourAppName.dll"]`

Instead, per the Heroku docs you should use the following:

`CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet YourAppName.dll`

Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` in your Dockerfile. See [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime):

> CMD is required. If CMD is missing, the registry will return an error
>   CMD will always be executed by a shell so that config vars are made available to your process; to execute single binaries or use images without a shell please use ENTRYPOINT